# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen when using a component with react-rails gem

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, react-rails

I am using rails 5.1.7 with the gem react-rails.

I added a react component in a erb view as:

```
<%= react_component("cardlist", { all_cards: @all_cards }, {prerender: true}) %>
```

Which works fine on my local environment, but when deploying the app to heroku, if I try to access the erb containing the `react_component` helper I get the following message in the logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/public/packs/js/server_rendering-7bdf65f03078e0e44c86.js
```

---

I have tried adding an App component as well and rendering that instead, but it keeps giving the same messages.

I have also added a node buildpack on heroku and I ensured the app only uses npm instead of yarn, with the node version added:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.3"
  }
```

But I always get the same message

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/public/packs/js/server_rendering-7bdf65f03078e0e44c86.js
```

---

If I set pre render to true the component appears in production with no errors on the log, but I need it done with server rendering.

---

After deleting the files in public/packs and compiling in the production environment as Justing suggested I am getting:

```
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341918+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-09-30T05:35:06.341829 #4] FATAL -- : [ce9e5a3a-b642-4de0-bb80-e4210172c687] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find server_rendering.js in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341919+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341919+00:00 app[web.1]: unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341920+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341921+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341921+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341922+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341922+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341923+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-09-30T05:35:06.341923+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2020-09-30T05:35:06.342250+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-09-30T05:35:06.342174 #4] FATAL -- : [ce9e5a3a-b642-4de0-bb80-e4210172c687]     44:         <% @hotel_search_filter = t :hotel_search__filter %>
2020-09-30T05:35:06.342252+00:00 app[web.1]: [ce9e5a3a-b642-4de0-bb80-e4210172c687]     46:         <%= @count_filters = count_filters %>
2020-09-30T05:35:06.342255+00:00 app[web.1]: [ce9e5a3a-b642-4de0-bb80-e4210172c687]     47:         <%= react_component("App", { all_ro
```

My webpack config file:

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> works fine on my local environment

Did you try precompiling locally?

```
RAILS_ENV=production NODE_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Then run your rails app with

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

The error should be pretty obvious. My guess is that you have some error during the precompile so the file `js/server_rendering-7bdf65f03078e0e44c86.js` doesn't exist.

You might also want to ensure that you don't have any files in your /public/packs directory checked into your git repo.